# /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib is not a known library type

Tags: configuration, shared-library, error-handling

I was following this instruction on this site to installing tesseract: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

```
git clone https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract.git
cd tesseract
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

But there is a problem in the last line and I got this error messages when I tried `ldconfig`:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib is not a known library type
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig is not a known library type
```

What's that error meaning and how can I fix it?

This is the content of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` :

```
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: Did the `make` stage complete successfully? What is the output of `ls -ld /usr/local/lib{,/pkgconfig}`?

Comment: Yes, I didn't see  any errors in previous stages.
drwxrwsr-x 1 root staff 1030 Dec 13 16:11 /usr/local/lib
drwxr-sr-x 1 root staff   94 Dec 13 16:11 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Comment: run make test and post the result

Answer (score 0):

Yeah well you can't compile if your linker doesn't know where your libraries are. ldconfig is the utility that sets up your linked libraries and it's looking for you to tell it where your shared libraries are in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf. The problem is that in that conf file you have a grand total of ONE path listed, but it's saying that's not even a real path.

You need to add the proper paths to where you keep your shared libraries to ld.so.conf.

Instructions says you need to have leptonica-dev package installed in order to have those shared libraries since what you're trying to build depends on them to compile. I'm assuming you didn't since it can't find the shared libraries.

I'm kind of new to this site but it's weird how I can get docked points for providing a perfectly legitimate answer. Doesn't leave much incentive to help if their reward system is all screwed up.

Comment: What do you mean by shared libraries? I have downloaded the tesseract and it's in this path: ' /home/m/tesseract ' , and also I have these paths in my computer: ' /usr/local/lib ' and ' /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig '

Comment: No, that's not the problem. The problem is that a directory name is being parsed as a library file name somehow.

Comment: Yeah because you're telling it to in /etc/ld.conf.d/libc.conf that your libc shared libraries are in /usr/local/lib and it can't find them there and there's nothing there that the compiler identifies as a known library type.

Comment: Did you ensure the leptonica-dev package was installed first as per the instructions? If so, the shared libraries should be in that path.

Comment: Yes, I have installed leptonica 1.73 as how it says in method 2(with autoconf) in this site: leptonica.org/source/README.html, and its in this path: ' /home/m/leptonica-1.73'